# React API Context Router

Tags: reactjs

So I want to in the context API use it to call and get a token for my API calls. I will need that token when my route loads. When I console log, I see a context property but I do not see anything in it.

```
render() {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Consumer>
              {value => {
                return (
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/:account_name"
                    component={ServiceMenu}
                    context={value}
                  />
                );
              }}
            </Consumer>
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Then in my service menu component I was hoping that I could access it here

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.context.token);

  // Make more API calls that I can do now that I have the token
```

Here is the context I have built

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Context = React.createContext();

export class Provider extends Component {
  state = {
    token: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}/token`, null, {
        headers
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);

        this.setState({
          token: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const headers = {
  "Subscription-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_APIM_KEY
};

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

But like I said that context is empty. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you get in console for just `res` and not `res.data`? Are you able to confirm your backend api is receiving the post?

Comment: Yes, I get the token back eventually. Could it be that value might be empty at that time?

Comment: Ya, on first mount, the context is not set until after the component is mounted so you'll always see an empty context to start with at least until all the components have mounted and run their post mounted render. You might benefit from moving the axios post to a constructor to be run before the component mounts, or using the new React hooks as well as `async/await` to avoid promise chain hell

Comment: @Chimera.Zen Is there another component lifecycle that I can watch to see when I get the token?

Comment: Also, I just took out API call and just did straight object and still nothing

Comment: componentWillMount is deprecated and suggested to be moved to a constructor. I guess you could put the axios in a function and call it from the constructor. `constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  getData()
}`

I might be off on the constructor as I use hooks for all my state and lifecycle management and haven't used a constructor in a while.